# How to connect the SQLite database in my Android Application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I cant able to connect my android App with SQLite DataBase.I have tried many ways ,But i cant get the solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Lets see what have you tried.. Post your code..!

Comment: try to refer an example at http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html

Comment: how to connect database in my existing app

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect internal SQLite database in my Android Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401017/how-to-connect-internal-sqlite-database-in-my-android-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are references for SQLite Database in Android Application...

http://stdioe.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-connect-sqlite-database-in.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

hope this help you...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [SqlLite tutorial](http://www.hdelossantos.com/2010/01/07/using-a-sqlite-database-in-android/), but tell us more. May be you want connect not to internal SQLLite (like simple androids work), maybe you want connect to external SQLite server by ip-adress or else?

Comment: how to connect external sqllite server using ip address